# Slow wifi connection to Airport Extrem

Tags: wifi

When I connect my Nokia 620 (firmware 1030.6407.1308.0001) to my home wireless, an Airport extreme version 7.6.3, it takes 2 minuts to load a webpage and causes timeout errors in many other applications. However, I downloaded and ran the Network Speed test and it said my download speed is 11.43Mbps, my upload speed is 0.90 Mbps, and my ping is 111 ms with a 8.5 % packet loss so it does not seem to be an issue with my connection speed.

All the other computers on the network do not have this problem and load pages quickly. I have used the phone on the wireless at work and it performs at normal speeds (3-7 sec page loads). It also loads pages just fine on HSPA+. 
I have tried changing my security from WPA/WPA2 to just WPA2, and have tried switching the router to 802.11 g only mode. Neither action proved a solution.

What might be causing this issue, and what are some other steps I can take to troubleshoot and resolve it?

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE (June 23, 2014): I have update to to the Lumia Black update and the WP 8.1 developer preview (OS version 8.10.12397.895) and the issue still persists.

Comment: Do you have problems with your phone in other WiFi connection or it is a specific problem in this place?

Comment: I have only had this problem on this specific WiFi network. It has worked on all other networks I've tried.

Comment: Who is your wireless carrier?

Comment: @karancan It's an unlocked phone and I am going through AT&T, however, I doubt it is any issue with my data connection.

Comment: @dustin are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question to reflect the current state of my phone. @MikaelDúiBolinder

Comment: Have you tried removing the sim from your phone and then browse the web?

Comment: I have yet to try removing my sim card, though I have tried turning of cellular data in the settings. I don't have access to the AirPort right now, but I will update this post when I do.

Comment: I guess your 2.4GHz band is full of noise. Try switch channel, ask your neighbors to lower their output power, turn of old wireless equipment etc.

Comment: Also try to use the 5GHz band instead.